# Use the terminal background color for the emacs -nw

Tags: terminal-emacs, colors

I am looking for a way to force "emacs -nw" to use the same background color that the terminal uses. (just like vim does).
By default, every emacs theme has its own default background color. Whiteboard mode has white that is not the same white as my terminal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that setting the background color of the default font to an undefined value turns off any customization. This feels like a hack, and there might be a better way to do this, but this worked for me:

```lisp
;; init.el
(set-face-background 'default "undefined")
```

Of course, if "undefined" will ever be defined (haha) in the color palette, this will break.

Comment: that worked, thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `custom-set-faces` to just NOT set properties when using a tty, and then have other defaults for other types.

With the following, the `default` face gets foreground and background set unless the display type is `tty`, as it is when you run `emacs -nw`.

For some other things, I generally like the defaults, especially when using X11.  I override a handful of those when type is `tty`, and leave them alone otherwise.

Note that the `comment-face` is always set ... brightgreen for terminals, green1 otherwise (X11).

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.                                           
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.                    
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.                           
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.                               
 '(default ((((type tty)))
            (t (:background "#6F4700" :foreground "yellow" :slant normal :weight normal :width normal :foundry "default" :family "monospace"))))
 '(font-lock-comment-face ((((type tty)) (:foreground "brightgreen"))
                           (t (:foreground "green1"))))
 '(font-lock-builtin-face ((((type tty)) (:foreground "color-250"))))
 '(minibuffer-prompt ((((type tty)) (:foreground "cyan"))))
 '(font-lock-string-face ((((type tty)) (:foreground "orange")))))
```